# EF Linq to Entities calling ToList() on entity set generates SQL command containing multiple left outer join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

My entity **"Progetto"** map a view with name **VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup**

[image]

Progetto has five navigations property: ClienteDiFatturazione, ClienteDiLavorazione, PercentualeSuccesso, Agente having multiplicity 0..1 and DocumentiWcs having mupltiplicity *

When I run this simple statement in LINQPad

```
var prj = Progetti.AsQueryable(); 
prj.ToList();
```

the sql generated is

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
    [Extent1].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
    [Extent1].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
    [Extent1].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
    [Extent1].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
    [Extent1].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
    [Extent1].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
    [Extent1].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
    [Extent1].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo], 
    [Extent2].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
    [Extent3].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
    [Extent4].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo]
    FROM    (SELECT 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo]
    FROM [dbo].[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup] AS [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup]) AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo]
    FROM [dbo].[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup] AS [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup]) AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IdProgetto] = [Extent2].[IdProgetto]) AND ([Extent1].[IdSerie_Progetto] = [Extent2].[IdSerie_Progetto])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo]
    FROM [dbo].[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup] AS [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup]) AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IdProgetto] = [Extent3].[IdProgetto]) AND ([Extent1].[IdSerie_Progetto] = [Extent3].[IdSerie_Progetto])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
    [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo]
    FROM [dbo].[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup] AS [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup]) AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent4].[IdPercentuale_Successo] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IdProgetto] = [Extent4].[IdProgetto]) AND ([Extent1].[IdSerie_Progetto] = [Extent4].[IdSerie_Progetto])
```

I wonder why the generated SQL query involves so many left outer join; i would expect a simple select on VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup. What is the purpose of this behavior?
Being the entity mapped to a View  multiple joins have a heavy impact on query performance. Any workaround?

**UPDATE**
Being VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup a view I had to manually add all the associations and navigation properties (no fk defined at database level so no associations generated when model has been created from database)

IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione refers to ClienteDIfatturazione, IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione refers to ClienteDiLavorazione, IdPercentuale_Successo refers to PercentualeSuccesso and IdAgente to Agente, I just renamed the field in the model so their name are a little differente from the fields in the view.

This is the code of Progetto class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace EntityModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Progetto
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Progetto()
        {
            this.DocumentiWcs = new HashSet<DocumentoWcsProgetto>();
        }

        public int Codice { get; set; }
        public int Serie { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Importo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataPrevistaChiusura { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdStato { get; set; }
        public string Oggetto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdMezzoPervenuto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdAgente { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> FidoResiduo { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente ClienteDiFatturazione { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente ClienteDiLavorazione { get; set; }
        public virtual PercentualeSuccesso PercentualeSuccesso { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<DocumentoWcsProgetto> DocumentiWcs { get; set; }
        public virtual Agente Agente { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here the DefiningQuery for the view VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup

```
      <EntitySet Name="VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup" EntityType="Self.VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdProgetto] AS [IdProgetto], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdSerie_Progetto] AS [IdSerie_Progetto], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Importo] AS [Importo], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdPercentuale_Successo] AS [IdPercentuale_Successo], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Data_Prevista_Chiusura] AS [Data_Prevista_Chiusura], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione] AS [IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdMezzo_Pervenuto] AS [IdMezzo_Pervenuto], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdStato] AS [IdStato], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Oggetto] AS [Oggetto], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[IdAgente] AS [IdAgente], 
[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup].[Fido_Residuo] AS [Fido_Residuo]
FROM [dbo].[VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup] AS [VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup]</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
```

Comment: It seems to me that `ClienteDiFatturazione, ClienteDiLavorazione, PercentualeSuccesso, Agente` are all mapped to the same view.

Comment: No they aren't. Whay make you think like that? VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup is the view that Progetto maps to

Comment: The select statement seems to contain fields that are not in the `Progetto` entity (f.e. `IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione`), so I suspect that they are mapped to other entities.

Comment: Not really as IdAnagrafica_Fatturazione refers to ClienteDIfatturazione, IdAnagrafica_Lavorazione refers to ClienteDiLavorazione, IdPercentuale_Successo refers to PercentualeSuccesso and IdAgente to Agente, I just renamed the field in the model so their name are a little differente from the fields in the view.

Comment: Did you make any other modifications to the edmx after it was generated from the database? Esp. in terms of relationships?

Comment: Yes of course being VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup a view  I had to manually add all the associations and navigation properties (no fk defined at database level  so no associations generated when model has been created from database)

Comment: If you look in the edmx (as XML), what do you find as `<DefiningQuery>` for the view?

Comment: Can you post the (generated) code for `Progetto` class? Also please specify the EF version used.

Comment: Ok I posted my class my EF version is 6.1.3

Comment: What I hoped to see was where the `IdProgetto` and `IdSerie_Progetto` (used in generated left outer joins) come from, which unfortunately is still unclear from the posted information. They seem to be setup as the PK of the "entity"? Are you sure you haven't defined some self relationship?

Comment: @Ivan These fields must have been mapped to `Codice` and `Serie` because they are marked as keys in the edmx. A self-reference isn't visible in the image, but then, only two of the five navigation properties are visible as associations. Ghini Antonio, is this a sub diagram in the edmx? Also, can you elaborate on how you created the associations, i.e. the *exact* steps you took to create them?

Comment: @Gert This is what I thought, but wanted to be sure and also see the associations. Hate edmx, it's hard to figure out something looking at screenshot only and no mcve :)

Comment: @Gert is right what you see is a screen captures of part of a sub-diagram. You don't see the other associations because the entities involved are on different diagrams.  The associations are all independence associations, created adding the association on diagram and mapping the relations on their own tables and views.

Comment: sounds like eager loading multiple levels. if you use, this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;, does this change your tsql?

Comment: @GhiniAntonio Nice, but the problem apparently is in the associations which unfortunately we don't see. Good luck.

Comment: Let me first ask this, if you have a specific Progetto record that has a specific Cliente can you use a .where clause to select said Progetto and does this Progetto object have the correct Cliente?  Is there only the expected one Progetto or does it return many Progetto objects, this might be best if tested with a Progetto that has more than one Cliente type.  I just want to make sure everything is working correctly and returning expected results.

Comment: It's surprising to see navigation tables are not linked via a foreign key in the underlying database. It may sound weird but only way to enhance this is with defining the relation with a foreign key. Lets say you have 5 tables in existing DB. Extract the data ( use some conditions as per you need in where clause ) and store them in 5 different list. you know where exactly is the relation between them , so filter out what list is linked to what (List1 linked to List2 by Id1) ---> filtered . Next List2 & list3 and so on..

Comment: Trying my guess too... The problem seems to be in the query definition, as the defining query for entity type VW_AMY_PRG_WCS_Lookup performs a select into the view itself. The SELECT statement should browse some table(s) instead.

Comment: I think the problem is about nullable foreign keys. Because of your db fields are defined as int not null and your entity fields are defined as nullable int, EF tries to left join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that you do not use `Select` in your query. Therefore the original classes are selected.

You should select only the properties you really plan to use.

Below is the tested solution that will only join the tables used in your requests. Alas my Italian(?) is a bit rusty, so forgive me if I do not use the correct identifiers.

```
var result = myDbContext.Progretti           
    .Select(progret => new                 // from every Progret make one new object
    {                                      // containing only the properties you plan to use
        Id = progret.Id,
        Name = progret.Name

        ProgrettiDiFacturazione = new      // you can even use properties from other tables
        {                                  // again: only properties you plan to use
             Name = progret.ProgrettiDiFacturazione.Name
             Date = progret.ProgrettiDiFacturazione.Date,
             ...
        },
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

DbSet implements IQueryable, so you won't need `AsQueryable`

If you have designed your one-to-many (many-to-many?) classes correctly, entity framework is smart enough to understand which table joins are needed for this. it won't join tables  if no properties are requested from that table.