# Entity Framework the sql statement contains odd self join with entity having composite primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

EF 6.1.3  (database first)
.net framework 4.6.1

simple mapping between two tables like the following picture show
[image]
here the generated diagram (auto-generated by the wizard)
[image]

the statement
`Tic_Tickets_new.AsQuerable().Dump()` is translated in the following sql query

```
 SELECT 
        [Extent1].[IdSerie_Ticket] AS [IdSerie_Ticket], 
        [Extent1].[IdTicket] AS [IdTicket], 
        [Extent2].[IdNatura] AS [IdNatura]
        FROM  [dbo].[Tic_Tickets_new] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Tic_Tickets_new] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[  IdNatura] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[IdSerie_Ticket] = [Extent2].[IdSerie_Ticket])
    AND ([Extent1].[IdTicket] = [Extent2].[IdTicket])
```

surprise! what is the **purpose of the join**? It seems totally  unusefull

Removing the composite primary key and using in place a single field surrogated key the generate sql statement get simple and smooth without any join

**UPDATE**
With reference to the comments may be I need to clear the intent of this post; the behavior I explained above is a behavior I already verified on differents projects (database first) when I attempt to load entities partecipating to a * to 0..1 association  or 0..1 to 0..1,  having a composite primary key and having the associon defined as Independent Association and lazy loading enable; so I consider this as a behavior by design. I already have a workaround and the workaround is to change the type of association from Independent Association to Foreign Key Association.
But the question is WHY?

Comment: Does the query work?  It looks like somebody wanted to make sure that IdNatura and IdTicket were unique one-to-one when inserting the data.

Comment: Sure it works but the example  is a simplified case, in my real case i have a lot of navigation properties (associations) like the one above and for every association a new join is added in the SQL statement making performance  worst and worst

Comment: Taking into account your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203774/ef-linq-to-entities-calling-tolist-on-entity-set-generates-sql-command-contain), I think we need a full [mcve].

Comment: I think we need to see your Fluent API/Data Annotation attributes on the POCO here to really make a guess as to why this is happening.  It is possible some weird FK is referring back to itself in code somewhere.

Comment: ORMs often generate bad queries. Accept that.